# How to express assignment to indexed arrays less verbose?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I am coming from python and there I can do the following with `numpy.ndarray`

```py
import numpy as np

res = np.zeros(4, dtype=np.float32)
x = np.array([2, 3, 4, 5])
res[0:2] = -x[2:4]
print(res)
>>> [-4 -5 0 0]
```

I tried to do the same thing with the `ndarray` crate but it is very verbose. Especially due to the unary minus which I could not directly apply to the sliced array, but had to apply it to whole `x` and then take a slice from it.

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;

let mut res = Array1::<f32>::zeros(4);
let x = array![2f32, 3., 4., 5.];
res.slice_mut(s![0..2]).assign(&(-x).slice(s![2..4]));
println!("{}", res);
>>> [-4, -5, 0, 0]
```

Plus, it looks kinda nasty compared to just doing it for each index separately in case of a small array.

```rust
use ndarray::prelude::*;

let mut res = Array1::<f32>::zeros(4);
let x = array![2f32, 3., 4., 5.];
res[[0]] = -x[2];
res[[1]] = -x[3];
println!("{}", res);
>>> [-4, -5, 0, 0]
```

So can I do this better? Is there a more idiomatic way that looks something like the second approach for rust but is scalable for big arrays? I am asking this, because I think my first approach makes understanding the code really hard. I still have a bug in my actual code, where the first approach doesn't work. I think I simply made a mistake, because the toy example here works. But that's kind of my point. It is hard to read and easy to make mistakes with the verbose syntax.

I am using cargo 1.55.0 and ndarray="0.15.3".

Comment: Perhaps you need to break your real code down into smaller steps for each of which you write some unit tests?